# enhanced for loop stops recognizing variable

Tags: java, variables, foreach

I'm trying to make a bukkit plugin, but this is a java problem. I have an enhanced for loop that, for some reason, only recognizes the declared loop variable in one specific instance. Here is an excerpt of the code:

```
for(String categoryName : catString)
    {

        if(this.getConfig().getConfigurationSection("Shops." + ShopName + ".Categories." + categoryName).getKeys(false).contains("SubCategories"))//If it has subcategories
        {

            Set<String> subCategories = this.getConfig().getConfigurationSection("Shops." + ShopName + ".Categories." + categoryName + ".SubCategories").getKeys(false);
            String[] subCatString = new String[subCategories.size()];
            int subCatAmount = subCategories.size();
            holder = subCatAmount;
            pageAmount = 0;

            while(holder > 0)
            {

                pageAmount++;
                holder -= 45;

            }

            Inventory[] subCategoryInvs = new Inventory[pageAmount];

            cellIndex = 0;
            pageIndex = 0;
            holder = categoryAmount;
            placeHolder = null; //Placeholder Inventory, will be loaded into the HashMap later, set to null so that it is fresh for subcategories.


            while(pageIndex < pageAmount)
            {
```

The line with the if statement recognizes the variable "categoryName", but in the very next line of code, where the Set is defined, I get a red underline telling me that "categoryName" is not a variable. In addition, if I add a statement before the if statement that uses "categoryName" in any way whatsoever, I am told that it isn't a variable. What gives?

BTW, I am using Eclipse, if that is relevant. Also, no, this isn't the complete for loop.

EDIT: I was able to work around it by using the non-enhanced for loop, meaning that instead of using categoryName, I had to use catString[index], which is fine, I guess. I'm still wondering what was wrong with my original for loop, as I used the same variable name throughout.

Comment: Try copying the name from where it works, and pasting it where it doesn't. The most common cause of this problem is two variable names that are highly similar, but not identical.

Comment: I have tried that to no avail. I've even tried restarting eclipse, and retyping the for loop. For some reason, it only accepts it as a variable in that one line. @AndyThomas

Comment: If it's the same name and in the body of the `for` loop, it should be in scope and usable. Another possible error to check is whether you have any extraneous braces that close the `for` loop scope earlier than you thought. But that seems unlikely since a trivial change from a for-each to a counted iteration eliminated the issue. Another unlikely cause would be if you were using a version of Java before Java 5, when for-each loops were introduced.

Comment: Have you tried compiling the supposedly non-working code? It could be just some bug with Eclipse.

Comment: Is the problem just that Eclipse is showing the error, or that it actually doesn't run? If it is just Eclipse, check the Java settings for your project (as well as the installed version of Java that Eclipse is using). As suggested by @AndyThomas, the problem might be that Eclipse is flagging a potential issue due to the Java compliance settings.

Comment: Side note: `this.` prepended to a method call is superfluous.